# How to treat non-normal measurement noise in a Kalman filter? Plus, how to treat non-zero mean of noise in Kalman filter?

Tags: residuals, kalman-filter, noise

Typically in textbooks, it is assumed that measurement noise $\nu_{t}$ is normally distributed. Suppose that $S_{t}$ is a signal. Then a measurement equation is

$$
S_{t} = x_{t} +\nu_{t} $$
where $$ \nu_{t} \sim WN(0,\sigma_{\nu}^2)$$

However,my signal data has the following structure:
$$
S_{t}= \beta_0+\beta_{x}x_{t}+\nu_{t}
$$
If I omit a constant term $\beta_0$ then, the mean of residuals (noise term $\nu_{t}$) is non-zero so it breaks the normality assumption.

Q1. Can I keep the constant term? I haven't found a textbook allowing a constant term in the measurement equation.

Q2. Even keeping the constant term, noise is not normally distributed. What can I do to meet the normality assumption?

Q3. A signal $S_{t}$ is way more fluctuating than $x_{t}$. Does it mean that signal's too much 'noisy and inaccurate'? If a shock happens, the signal goes much higher or lower than the unobserved variable.